# How to add a class or id wrapper to a

Tags: views

I added a footer to a view and I need to give this footer a wrapper class or id. How can I accomplish with this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also theme this footer using the oft forgotten cascading properties of CSS, eg, if your view is named foobarbaz:

```
 .view-foobarbaz .view-footer {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

will make all the footer text bold and red.

Answer (score 1):

You  an can put HTML in there, just make sure you choose an Input Format (Text Formats in D7) that allows you to use the HTML tags you'll be putting in there.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourfooter').addClass('yourClass');
```

Or views-view--YOURVIEWNAME.tpl.php and you can add you class there.

Do you want to give it to the footer or to the field?
You can even write in the field `<div class="yourclass">it is easier to smash an atom than a prejudice.</div>`